# how to add product inside a php page when after executing the insert query

Tags: php, mysql

php file

```
 <?php
 require_once('conn.php');
 $itemId= (\filter_input(\INPUT_GET,'itemId'));
 $sql="select img from getdesserticecream  where itemId='$itemId'";
 $res=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
 //$row=  \mysqli_fetch_array($res);
 //$subtitle=$row['subtitle'];
 $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
 //mysqli_close($dbhandle);
 header("Content-type: image");
 stripslashes($row['img']);
 ?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Customer menu card</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dessert.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id='custdisp' name='custdisp' method='post' onload='return display()'  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <script src="samcheck.js"></script>
        <div id="top">
        <?php session_start(); ?>
      <div id="toplbl">Welcome <?php  echo $_SESSION["name"]?></div>
      <?php session_start(); ?>
      <div id="toplbl1">This is Table Number <?php  echo $_SESSION["tnumber"]?></div>

      <input type="hidden" style="position: absolute;top:200px;" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["custno"]?>">
  </div>
    <div id="container">

        <div id="header" >
            <img id="headerimage" src="../samproject/contentimg.jpg" alt="image"/>
            <label id="headerlbl1">Order </label>
            <label id="headerlbl2">Eat</label>
            <label id="headerlbl3">Pay !!!! </label>
       </div>

        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Starter</a>           
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="customersvsoup.php">Veg</a></li>


                    <li><a href="customersnvsoup.php">NonVeg</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Main Course</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="customermcvsundries.php">Veg</a></li>
                    <li><a href="customermcnvricedishes.php">NonVeg</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="customerdicecream.php">Dessert</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> 
    <div id="content">
    <nav id="n1">
    <ul id="ul1">
    <li id="li1">    <a href="#">I want to see ----></a>

      <ul id="ul2"> 
          <li id="li2"><a href="customerdicecream.php">Ice cream</a></li>
          <li id="li3"><a href="customerdsalad.php">Salad and Cakes</a></li>
            <li id="li4"><a href="customerdshake.php">Milk shake</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </ul>
    </nav>  

  <div id="portfolio1">
  <?php  $sql1="select subtitle from dessert where itemId='oepd1007'";
  $res1=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql1);
  $row1= mysqli_fetch_array($res1);
  $subtitle1=$row1['subtitle'];?> <?php echo $subtitle1 ?></div>
  <div id="portfolio2">
  <?php  $sql2="select subtitle from dessert where itemId='oepd5148'";
  $res2=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql2);
  $row2= mysqli_fetch_array($res2);
  $subtitle2=$row2['subtitle'];?> <?php echo $subtitle2 ?></div>
  <div id="portfolio3">
  <?php  $sql3="select subtitle from dessert where itemId='oepd1004'";
  $res3=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql3);
  $row3= mysqli_fetch_array($res3);
   $subtitle3=$row3['subtitle'];?> <?php echo $subtitle3 ?></div>
   <div id="portfolio4">
  <?php  $sql4="select subtitle from dessert where itemId='oepd1008'";
  $res4=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql4);
  $row4= mysqli_fetch_array($res4);
  $subtitle4=$row4['subtitle'];?> <?php echo $subtitle4 ?></div>
  <div id="portfolio5">
  <?php  $sql5="select subtitle from dessert where itemId='oepd1522'";
  $res5=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql5);
 $row5= mysqli_fetch_array($res5);
 $subtitle5=$row5['subtitle'];?> <?php echo $subtitle5 ?></div>
 <div id="portfolio6">
  <?php  $sql6="select subtitle from dessert where itemId='oepd1002'";
  $res6=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql6);
  $row6= mysqli_fetch_array($res6);
  $subtitle6=$row6['subtitle'];?> <?php echo $subtitle6 ?></div>
  <div id="portfolio7">
  <?php  $sql7="select subtitle from dessert where itemId='oepd1003'";
  $res7=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql7);
  $row7= mysqli_fetch_array($res7);
  $subtitle7=$row7['subtitle'];?> <?php echo $subtitle7 ?></div>
  <div id="portfolio8">
  <?php  $sql8="select subtitle from dessert where itemId='oepd1001'";
  $res8=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql8);
  $row8= mysqli_fetch_array($res8);
  $subtitle8=$row8['subtitle'];?> <?php echo $subtitle8 ?></div>
  <div id="portfolio9">
  <?php  $sql9="select subtitle from dessert where itemId='oepd1005'";
  $res9=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql9);
  $row9= mysqli_fetch_array($res9);
  $subtitle9=$row9['subtitle'];?> <?php echo $subtitle9 ?></div>
  <div id="portfolio10">
  <?php  $sql10="select subtitle from dessert where itemId='oepd1010'";
  $res10=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql10);
  $row10= mysqli_fetch_array($res10);
  $subtitle10=$row10['subtitle'];?> <?php echo $subtitle10 ?></div>
  <div id="portfolio11">
  <?php  $sql11="select subtitle from dessert where itemId='oepd1011'";
  $res11=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql11);
  $row11= mysqli_fetch_array($res11);
  $subtitle11=$row11['subtitle'];?> <?php echo $subtitle11 ?></div>
  <div id="portfolio12">
  <?php  $sql12="select subtitle from dessert where itemId='oepd1006'";
  $res12=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql12);
  $row12= mysqli_fetch_array($res12);
  $subtitle12=$row12['subtitle'];?> <?php echo $subtitle12 ?></div>
  <ul id="grid">
  <li>
  <a href="samcheckdb.php?itemId=oepd1007">    <img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd1007" alt="image" id="img1"></a></li> 
<li>  <a href="samcheckdb.php?itemId=oepd5148"><img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd5148" alt="image" id="img2"></a></li> 
<li>  <a href="samcheckdb.php?itemId=oepd1004"> <img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd1004" alt="image" id="img3"></a> </li>
<li> <a href="samcheckdb.php?itemId=oepd1008">  <img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd1008" alt="image" id="img4" > </a></li> 
<li> <a href="samcheckdb.php?itemId=oepd1522"> <img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd1522" alt="image" id="img5" ></a> <li> 
<li><a href="samcheckdb.php?itemId=oepd1002">  <img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd1002" alt="image" id="img6" ></a> </li> 
<li> <a href="samcheckdb.php?itemId=oepd1003"> <img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd1003" alt="image" id="img7"> </a></li> 
<li> <a href="samcheckdb.php?itemId=oepd1001"> <img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd1001" alt="image" id="img8"></a></li> 
<li>  <a href="samcheckdb.php?itemId=oepd1005">   <img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd1005" alt="image" id="img9"></a> </li>
<li>  <a href="samcheckdb.php?itemId=oepd1010">   <img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd1010" alt="image" id="img10"></a> </li>
<li>  <a href="samcheckdb.php?itemId=oepd1011">   <img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd1011" alt="image" id="img11"> </a></li>
<li>  <a href="samcheckdb.php?itemId=oepd1006">   <img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId=oepd1006" alt="image" id="img12"></a> </li>
  </ul>

    </div>
    </div>
    </form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have retrieved all the images from database and display in the php file, but as soon as I insert them into the database I need the images to be displayed in this file.

I'm doing this by giving the `itemId`, but I don't know how to give `$itemId` and retrieve all the images..

Comment: where is this said insert ?

Comment: it is in another file. i have not added here

Comment: I don't understand why you have so many repeating queries. Why not get all the images you need and loop through them? Do you need all the images or is it based on certain categories?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger actually i'm inserting the details of a item like name,title,subtitle,price,itemId,img,i retrive all the images from db into a file,there is no category, as soon as i add there i need that to be added even here

Comment: Ok so since you have hard-coded ids here you means you want to load all the images dynamically?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger yes all the images i have retrieved staticaly

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger  u please help me. is my question clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, right after your menu closes, put in this code:

```
  /* Your menu code */
  </ul>
</nav> 

<?php
  $results = array();
  $res = mysqli_query($dbhandle,'select subtitle,itemId from dessert');
  # We are going to fetch all the subtitle and itemId from your table
  while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    # And save it in an array
    $results[] = array('subtitle'=>$row['subtitle'],'itemId'=>$row['itemId']);
  }

 # Now, let's display the portfolio div elements first
 foreach($results as $key=>$val){
    echo "<div id='portfolio{$key}'>".$val['subtitle']."</div>";
 }

 # And then the images:
 echo "<ul id='grid'>";

 #using the same array again but this time it will be the itemId
 foreach($results as $key=>$val){
    echo '<li><a href="samcheckdb.php?itemId='.$val['itemId'].'"><img src="getdesserticecreamimage.php?itemId='.$val['itemId'].'" alt="image" id="img'.$key.'"></a></li>';
 }

 ?>
```

It's that simple. You need to learn to shorten your code by looping through the common pattern after all database connections are expensive - make use of more resources and time.